# Вывод значения на основе входных данных

Tags: c#

Есть некая таблица с данными, которая поступает на вход. Необходимо основываясь на входных данных получить выходные. Например так:

```
Если Колонка1 = "Значение1" И Колонка2 = "Значение2" ИЛИ Колонка1 содержит "Занчение3", то возвращаем "Значение10"
```

При этом сложность условия не ограничивается (можно группировать условия - ставить скобки). Все **ЗначенияN** известны (указываются пользователем). Как такое реализовать? С чего начать? Думаю здесь будет хорошим решением использовать, например, `LUA` или другой скриптовый язык - тогда вопрос какой лучше взять. Но так же очень интересуют идеи по реализации этого на самом C#.

Comment: А в чём проблема с C#? В нём тоже есть `if` и сравнение строк.

Comment: @VladD, интересует как организовать структуру данных, чтобы пользователь, грубо говоря, мог кликами мышки создавать эти условия

Comment: @Donil: Понял. Не видел ещё ни одной системы, где было бы _удобно для пользователя_ задавать подобные условия. Если вы сможете разработать — почёт вам и уважение.

Comment: @VladD, что-то подобное видел в SSMS или в MS Access, не помню точно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем пришло мне в голову организовать это в виде дерева, где между несколькими узлами одного родителя действовало бы `ИЛИ`, а между родителем и потомком `И`. Проиллюстрирую для лучшего понимания:

[image]

Алгоритм будет такой:

1. Между условиями C, D и E выполняем ИЛИ, т.к. у них один родитель. И получим узел G (фиктивный)
2. Теперь между A и G выполняем И, т.к. G (по факту это три условия объеденненые через ИЛИ) является дочерним по отношению к A
3. Таким же образом обходим все дерево

И если результат вычисления по всему дереву ИСТИНА, то присваиваем результат.

На C# это выглядит следующим образом:
Сначала определяем класс `Condition:`

```
public class Condition
    {
        public Condition()
        {
            Childrens = new ObservableCollection<Condition>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Поле строки по которому проверяется условие
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field")]
        public string Field { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Тип сравнения
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConditionType")]
        public ConditionType ConditionType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// С чем сравнивать
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comparer")]
        public string Comparer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Подусловия
        /// </summary>
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Childrens"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Children")]
        public ObservableCollection<Condition> Childrens { get; set; }
    }
```

Определяем класс `Rule`:

```
 public class Rule
    {
        private DataRow _dataRow;

        public Rule()
        {
            Conditions = new ObservableCollection<Condition>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Условия правила
        /// </summary>
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Conditions"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Condition")]
        public ObservableCollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Значение, которое будет установлено, если условие выполнится
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Result")]
        public string Result { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Вернет результат выполнения правила по данным
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="row">Данные для проверки</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsSuccess(DataRow row)
        {
            _dataRow = row;
            // Начальный результат корня полагаем "ложь"
            bool result = false;
            // Получаем результат дочерних
            foreach (Condition c in Conditions)
            {
                result |= CheckSuccess(c);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private bool CheckSuccess(Condition condition)
        {
            // Если дочерних узлов нет, полагаем их результат "истина" иначе "ложь"
            bool result = condition.Childrens.Count == 0;
            // Вычисляем результат дочерних узлов
            foreach (Condition child in condition.Childrens)
            {
                result |= CheckSuccess(child);
            }
            // Текущий и его дочерние узлы связвает опертор "И"
            return result && _dataRow[condition.Field].ToString() == condition.Comparer;
        }
    }
```

Сохраняем для нужно поля коллекцию правил и для вычисления значения пробегаемся по коллекции правил и как только `Rule.IsSuccess` вернет `true` останавливаемся и присваиваем значение `Rule.Result`.

На мой взгляд такой подход позволяет составить условие любой сложности и вложенности, а так же конструировать эти условия "мышкой" (отобразить правило на тот же TreeView не составит никакой сложности)

Какое-то не хорошее описание получилось, но времени нет все крисиво и понятно оформить. Жду комментариев и конструктивной критики

Comment: вы так не любите пользователей? посмотрите на [фильтр в 1с](http://fmc.uz/main.php?op=otbor). не надо делать слишком сложно. тройной уровень вложенности **и** и **или** не всякий мозг сможет осилить.  
кстати сказать у devEx'ов есть фильтр к гриду, на редкость неудобный, как раз там такое дерево с AND'ами и OR'ами...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ну ничего лучше под предъявляемые требования придумать не смог. Помоему, это в любом случае лучше написания условий на каком-нибудь скриптовом языке

Comment: чем сложнее система, тем меньше ей будут пользоваться. это касается и деревьев и скриптов. фильтры должны работать максимально просто иначе быстрее в эксель, там автофильтр, пару кликов и готово.  
если задачу ставит заказчик, то у него и надо спросить как ему будет удобнее редактировать, если вы сами принимаете решение что и как, то, имхо, лучше задуматься о более простом решении.  

ЗЫ Я пишу про фильтр для грида конкретно, вполне у вас возможна другая задача...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, нет у меня задача, в которой обычный грид, к сожалению, не поможет:) Да и этой системой будет пользоваться не каждый, а те, кто будет знать что и как делать

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте DataGrid с первой колонкой - чекбоксом выбора условия, второй - ComboBox названия условия (Значение + номер), третьей - операцией (=, <, > и т.д), четвертой - значением для операцией (типа значение1 = 123) и пятой - связтю между условиями (AND/OR).

На форму с DataGrid - кнопку "Apply", в хэндлере кнопки - сборка условия из DataGrid в строку с логическим выражением.

Конечно, коряво написал, но суть идеи вроде ясна.

А саму логику возврата значения напишите на основании собранного условия из DataGrid. То есть функция вида:

```
string returnValue(string condition)
{
   return parseCondition(condition);
}
```

где `parseCondition(string str)` - функция распознавания вашего условия, возвращающая нужное вам значение (для примера написал что его тип - string).

Ну и для загрузки данных в DataGrid Из DataTable используйте метод

```
DataGrid.Load(table);
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как в таком решении учитывать скобки. ИМХО, прикрутить Lua или Python гораздо проще. Так и геморроя с обработкой условий меньше, и гибкость решения больше.

Comment: @fori1ton, вы уверены что прикрутить Lua или Python к .net приложению проще, чем дописать логику? я не работал ни с Lua, ни с Python, но мне кажется что раз приложение на шарпеЮ то не надо вкручивать туда что-то иное. хотя я допускаю что ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Макс, Lua -  скриптовый язык специально созданный для того, чтобы его встраивали в другие приложения. То, что хочет реализовать ТС без написания собственного лексического анализатора и интерпретатора реализовать очень трудно (ещё раз напоминаю про скобки и вложенность). А для Lua есть готовые коннекторы для многих языков. Ещё можно попробовать с CSharpCodeProvider поиграть. Тоже скриптование, но на C#, без привлечения торонних скриптовых языков.

Comment: Такая реализация, помоему, не справится с вложенностью